# Move tool in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Why does the move tool always default to moving a path? I've had this behaviour across a number of versions of Gimp. It doesn't seem sensible when layers is the first option. Is there a way to fix this/force it to default to layers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default is to move layers. Reset it to Layers and go to `Edit>Preferences>Tool options>General` and click `Save tool options now` (also uncheck `Save tool options on exit` but this should already be the case otherwise you wouln't be asking here). This saves all your Tool options for all your tools, plus the current colors, pattern, gradient, palette, font... so make sure these are correct first

A more extreme way is to click `Reset tool options to default values`.

Comment: Thanks, tried both and no change.  It still seems to jump to move path.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Tool options? (btw, this is more for SuperUser)

Comment: I meant the Tools options dialog for the Move tool (`Windows>Dockable dialogs>Tool options`), not the Preferences thing :)

Comment: @garretlynch On that picture the Move tool is in `Layer` mode. So what makes you think it is in `Path` mode? Have you got any paths? Or is it just not moving the layer you want? If so try the `Move the active layer` option.  By default (the `Pick layer or guide` option) the tool infers which layer you want to pick by finding the topmost non-transparent pixel where you click. So if you want to move text, for instance, you have to click on the letters, not between them (or inside a loop). You can also toggle that option temporarily by using Shift-Click instead of a plain click.